# Adding --deploy-url in angular 8 breaks the code

Tags: angular, deployment

Using --deploy-url worked fine till my project angular version was 7. As soon as I updated to 8, it started giving the following error. [image: Cannot GET /]

Tried adding --base-href option but no use.

I'm pretty sure that it is the --deploy-url option that is causing issues as after removing it, the application runs but gives unauthorized access while getting some resources. So I think it might be because of removing the --deploy-url option.

Adding package.json and angular.json file. Any input would be helpful. Let me know if anything else is needed from my side.

The command I use for deployment is npm run localhost.

Angular.json file.

```js
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "PatientViewer": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.png",
              "src/ai.0.js",
              "src/ai.0.js.map",
              "src/icons/icon-72x72.png",
              "src/icons/icon-96x96.png",
              "src/icons/icon-128x128.png",
              "src/icons/icon-144x144.png",
              "src/icons/icon-152x152.png",
              "src/icons/icon-192x192.png",
              "src/icons/icon-384x384.png",
              "src/icons/icon-512x512.png",
              "src/params.json",
              "src/emrccd.xsl",
              "src/emrccdCVS.xsl",
              { "glob": "**/*", 
              "input": "src/assets", 
              "output": "/assets/" 
              }
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/theme.scss",
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [
            ]
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "extractCss": true,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PatientViewer:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "PatientViewer:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "PatientViewer:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "karmaConfig": "./karma.conf.js",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
            "codeCoverageExclude": [
              "src/*"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles/theme.scss",
              "src/styles/styles.scss"
            ],
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.png"
            ]
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "src/tsconfig.app.json",
              "src/tsconfig.spec.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    },
    "PatientViewer-e2e": {
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "",
      "projectType": "application",
      "architect": {
        "e2e": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:protractor",
          "options": {
            "protractorConfig": "./e2e/protractor.conf.js",
            "devServerTarget": "PatientViewer:serve"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "noserve": {
              "devServerTarget": ""
            }
          }
        },
        "lint": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
          "options": {
            "tsConfig": [
              "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json"
            ],
            "exclude": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "PatientViewer",
  "schematics": {
    "@schematics/angular:component": {
      "prefix": "app",
      "styleext": "scss"
    },
    "@schematics/angular:directive": {
      "prefix": "app"
    }
  }
}
```

Package.json file.

```js
{
  "name": "patient-viewer",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve --proxy-config proxy.conf.json --disableHostCheck true --deploy-url /assets/",
    "build": "npm run lint && ng build --progress --prod --deploy-url /assets/ && .\\node_modules\\.bin\\ngsw-config .\\dist\\ .\\ngsw-config.json /assets",
    "test": "ng test --code-coverage=true --watch=false --browsers=ChromeHeadless --source-map=false",
    "test-continuously": "ng test --watch=true --code-coverage=true --browsers=ChromeHeadless --source-map=false",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "prot": "cd .\\node_modules\\protractor && ng e2e --configuration=noserve",
    "smoke": "node smoke-test.js",
    "chromeDriver": "node chromeDriverInstall.js",
    "e2e": "npm run chromeDriver && protractor e2e\\protractor.conf.js --webdriverUpdate=false",
    "localhost": "ng serve --ssl --ssl-key .\\keyfile.key --proxy-config proxy.conf.json  --disableHostCheck true --deploy-url /assets/"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.24",
    "@angular/animations": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/cdk": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/common": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/core": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/forms": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/material": "^7.3.7",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/pwa": "^0.803.9",
    "@angular/router": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/service-worker": "^8.2.14",
    "angular2-uuid": "^1.1.1",
    "applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.21",
    "axios": "^0.20.0",
    "azure-storage": "^2.10.2",
    "classlist.js": "^1.1.20150312",
    "core-js": "^2.5.7",
    "find-chrome-version": "^2.1.0",
    "font-awesome": "^4.7.0",
    "json-logic-js": "^1.2.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^2.2.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.10",
    "ngx-device-detector": "1.4.2",
    "ngx-print": "^1.2.0-beta.4",
    "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
    "protractor-html-reporter-2": "^1.0.4",
    "protractor-jasmine-retry": "^1.0.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.3.3",
    "save-as": "^0.1.8",
    "tslib": "^2.3.1",
    "web-animations-js": "^2.3.2",
    "webdriver-manager": "^12.1.7",
    "yargs-parser": "^15.0.1",
    "zone.js": "~0.10.2"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.3.29",
    "@angular/compiler": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^8.2.14",
    "@angular/language-service": "^8.2.14",
    "@iarna/rtf-to-html": "^1.1.0",
    "@types/applicationinsights-js": "^1.0.9",
    "@types/fhir": "0.0.34",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.7",
    "@types/jwt-decode": "^2.2.1",
    "@types/node": "^10.17.21",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "copyfiles": "^2.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "^3.5.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "jasmine-trx-reporter": "^2.3.0",
    "karma": "^6.4.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^2.0.0",
    "karma-coverage": "^1.1.2",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^2.1.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "^5.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.3",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-trx-reporter": "^0.4.3",
    "phantomjs-prebuilt": "^2.1.13",
    "protractor": "^7.0.0",
    "puppeteer": "^1.20.0",
    "rimraf": "^2.7.1",
    "ts-node": "~8.0.0",
    "tslint": "^5.20.1",
    "typescript": "^3.5.3"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can you try adding below options and see if its working,

`ng serve --base-href "<requiredpath>" --serve-path "<requiredpath>" --public-host="http://localhost:4200"`
I think option `--deploy-url` is deprecated and we need to use `--base-href` instead.